# UIImagePickerController has two 'camera' buttons when started as front-facing

Tags: ios, ipad, uiimagepickercontroller, ios6

Since iOS6, whenever I show present a `UIImagePickerController` from inside a `UIPopoverController`, I am getting two "take picture" buttons:
 [image: Double camera button]

This only happens when starting out in front-facing mode.  If I start with the rear-camera and then switch after the popover appears, it's okay.  Likewise, starting in front-facing and switching to rear will keep the second button there.

Even worse, the 'in picture' button doesn't work.  It just tries to focus the camera at that point.

Anyone else seeing this or know of a solution?  It doesn't happen when presented full screen, and I saw in Apple's docs that the popover is no longer the recommended way to present the image picker, but that it's also not necessarily bad, either.  Unfortunately due to some external requirements, I need to keep it in a popover, and can't do full-screen.

Thanks!

Answer (score 1):

I have exactly the same issue on iOS6. Odd behavior is that it appears only the first time I open the image picker. When closed and opened again, "in-picture" button disappears. Looks like a bug in UIImagePickerController.

To overcome this issue, you can hide image controls by setting showsCameraControls property to NO and use custom overlay view with own controls. Disadvantage of this is that you have to provide all controls then and code action handlers for them.

Unfortunately I didn't find a better way so far.